# Upload files to a form

Tags: html, forms

I have a form on my website to allow clients to submit inquiries but I need to add the option of adding files, in this case, it would be photos. 
I can't find the proper solution for this. I'm new on this matter and I hope someone can help me.
Here it is the code i have about the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="<?=$form_name?>" id="<?=$form_name?>" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" >
<input type="hidden" name="lang" id="lang" value="<?=$_SESSION["lang"]?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="car_id" id="car_id" value="<?=$_SESSION["car_id"]?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="current_url" id="current_url" value="<?=$_SESSION["current_url"]?>" />

<!--NOME-->
<div class="form-group">
    <? $input_name = $form_name."_"."name"; ?>
    <label for="<?=$input_name?>"><?=NAME?>*</label>
    <input type="text" class="{target:'#<?=$input_name?>_status',tagToload:{'.<?=$input_name?>':'#<?=$input_name?>_status','.script':'#<?=$result_div?>'}} form-control watermark required" name="<?=$input_name?>" value="<?=$_POST[$input_name]?>" id="<?=$input_name?>" placeholder="<?=NAME_PLACEHOLDER?>">
</div>
<!--END NOME-->

<!--EMAIL-->
<div class="form-group">
    <? $input_name = $form_name."_"."email"; ?>
    <label for="<?=$input_name?>"><?=EMAIL?>*</label>
    <input type="email" class="{target:'#<?=$input_name?>_status',tagToload:{'.<?=$input_name?>':'#<?=$input_name?>_status','.script':'#<?=$result_div?>'}} form-control watermark required" name="<?=$input_name?>" value="<?=$_POST[$input_name]?>" id="<?=$input_name?>" placeholder="<?=EMAIL_PLACEHOLDER?>">
</div>
<!--END EMAIL-->

<!--SUBJECT-->
<div class="form-group">
    <? $input_name = $form_name."_"."subject_other"; ?>
    <label for="<?=$input_name?>"><?=SUBJECT?>*</label>
    <input type="text" class="{target:'#<?=$input_name?>_status',tagToload:{'.<?=$input_name?>':'#<?=$input_name?>_status','.script':'#<?=$result_div?>'}} form-control watermark required" name="<?=$input_name?>" value="<?=$_SESSION['subject']?>" id="<?=$input_name?>" placeholder="<?=SUBJECT_PLACEHOLDER?>" <?=(isset($_SESSION["subject"])) ? 'readonly="readonly"' : ''?>>
</div>
<!--END SUBJECT-->

<!--MESSAGE-->
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <? $input_name = $form_name."_"."message"; ?>
    <label for="<?=$input_name?>"><?=MESSAGE?>*</label>
    <textarea class="{target:'#<?=$input_name?>_status',tagToload:{'.<?=$input_name?>':'#<?=$input_name?>_status','.script':'#<?=$result_div?>'}} form-control watermark required" name="<?=$input_name?>" id="<?=$input_name?>" placeholder="<?=MESSAGE_PLACEHOLDER?>" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<!--END MESSAGE-->

<span class="blue_label blue_label_block blue_label_small" style="text-align: left;">* Campos de preenchimento obrigatório.</span>
<div class="form-group pull-right" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?=CLEAR?>">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default ml20" id="formSubmitLink_<?=$form_name?>" href="javascript:;"><?=SEND?></a>
</div>
<br class="clear">
<div class="resultForm" id="<?=$result_div?>"></div>
```

Comment: you should add more tags to your question, [html] comes to mind, also what language is your backend running on? that could be another tag, it's hard to answer without any context

Comment: Sorry, but its already hard for me to explain. I don´t know much of coding but let me edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="photo" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Photo</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="photo" placeholder="Photo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Deepak. It work's almost perfectly. I placed the code, I add the photo and it was submitted successfully but when receiving the form information its was missing the photo. Is it possible even to add more than one photo?

Comment: Welcome Andre...
As per your Current query, use <form enctype="multipart/form-data">. And yes, you can add more than one photo also by adding more than one file type form data otherwise by using some plugins. And if the code works, then go with a thumbsup